# python text template matching

Tags: python, text, nlp

I have to match the text with the regex template.
Here is the example:

```
templates = {"x":"welcome {1}, how can I help you","y":"hi {1},here is your concern {2}"}
input_text = "welcome john, how can I help you" # for this output should be "x"
input_text = "Hi john,here is your concern sick leave"# for this output shoud be "y"
input_text = "Welcome john, how can I help you, how are you?" # for this output should be None
input_text = "can I know your name" # for this output should be None
```

Could you please give some inputs to resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You asked a question and, in good faith, someone has taken the time and effort to answer your question. You have accepted their answer so I assume it is helpful to you. Please don't vandalise your question as it's very disrespectful to those who have helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to convert the templates into valid regex. Here, I replace `{1}` and `{2}` with the regex `.+`, which matches any non-empty chain of characters. Since the third example also requires an exact match and not a partial one, I add `$` to the regex to force it to match the text until the end.

`regex_temp = re.sub(r'\{\s*\d+\s*\}','.+',template) + '$'`

Then you just loop through the templates and test each one. The flag `re.I` makes it case insensitive as your examples contain upper and lower case text.

Another option would be to directly adapt the templates to be valid regex like this:
`templates = {"x":"welcome .+, how can I help you$","y":"hi .+,here is your concern .+"}` then you use the template as is in the regex and remove the string transformation above.

```
import regex as re
templates = {"x":"welcome {1}, how can I help you","y":"hi {1},here is your concern {2}"}

def find_template(input_text):
    for template_key, template in templates.items():
       regex_temp = re.sub(r'\{\s*\d+\s*\}','.+',template) + '$'
        if re.match(regex_temp, input_text, flags=re.I):
            return template_key
    return None

input_text = "welcome john, how can I help you" # for this output should be "x"
print(find_template(input_text))
input_text = "Hi john,here is your concern sick leave"# for this output shoud be "y"
print(find_template(input_text))
input_text = "Welcome john, how can I help you, how are you?" # for this output should be None
print(find_template(input_text))
input_text = "can I know your name" # for this output should be None
print(find_template(input_text))

>> x
>> y
>> None
>> None
```

Comment: Thank you for the valuable input.One change is needed here instead of `regex_temp = template.replace('{1}', '.+').replace('{2}', '.+') + '$` this I used `regex_temp = re.sub(r'\{\s*\d+\s*\}','.+',template) + '$'` which is suitable for all the reference numbers

Comment: I adapted the answer with your comment